# How can we embed bokeh layout objects (containing multiple plots and widgets) inside flask app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-applications, bokeh

I have a bokeh layout/curr_doc object and i want to embed it into flask app. I can embed all plots and widgets component wise but as a single layout i don't find any reference anywhere.The reason i want to embed full layout is that this will preserve the interactivity between plots and widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following example, it is in the examples folder in the GH project. You can check for more examples related to embedding [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed). You can also create an iframe and include all your application inside (though usually it is heavier for the browser). Check the [bryan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40323362/4891717) here as well, but take into account that in the latest bokeh versions you should use [`server_document`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/embed.html#bokeh.embed.server_document) instead of `autoload_server` as this example shows:

```
import atexit
import subprocess

from flask import render_template_string, Flask
from bokeh.embed import server_document

home_html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="bk-root">
      <h1><a href="/batch/1"> Batch 1 (cos)</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="/batch/2"> Batch 2 (sin)</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="/batch/3"> Batch 3 (tan)</a></h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
"""

app_html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div>
        <h2><a href="/batch/1">Batch 1 (cos)</a> - <a href="/batch/2">Batch 2 (sin)</a> - <a href="/batch/3">Batch 3 (tan)</a></h2>
    </div>
    {{ bokeh_script|safe }}
  </body>
</html>
"""

app = Flask(__name__)

bokeh_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python', '-m', 'bokeh', 'serve', '--allow-websocket-origin=localhost:5000', 'bokeh_server.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

@atexit.register
def kill_server():
    bokeh_process.kill()

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template_string(home_html)

@app.route('/batch/<int:batchid>')
def visualization(batchid):
    bokeh_script = server_document(url='http://localhost:5006/bokeh_server', arguments=dict(batchid=batchid))
    return render_template_string(app_html, bokeh_script=bokeh_script)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```